# How to show Map<String,List<String>> in Html in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

The response I'm getting in JS -

```
this.mapData:[{"key":"child1 for parent1","value":[["100","NEW Program123","2022-04-20 00:00:00","Active","2022-05-31 00:00:00"],["100","SkillUp","2022-03-22 00:00:00","Active","2022-05-31 00:00:00"]]},{"key":"child2 for parent1","value":[["null","NEW Program1234","2022-04-28 00:00:00","Active","2022-06-22 00:00:00"]]},{"key":"baburaj raj","value":[["200","checking","2022-04-15 00:00:00","Active","2022-09-23 00:00:00"]]}]
```

- I can't able to show it in HTML  -
  But I can't able to show in HTML -

```
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
          <th class="" scope="col">
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Key">Key</div>
          </th>
          <th class="" scope="col">
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Value">Value</div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
    <template for:each={mapData} for:item="mapkey" for:index="index">
        <tr key={mapkey.key}>
            <th scope="col">
             {mapkey.key}
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
            <template for:each={mapkey.value} for:item="mapval" for:index="index1">
              <div key={mapval}>
                {mapval}
              </div>
            </template>
          </th>
        </tr>
    </template>
```

I have got the response in this

```
@wire(getContacts)
wiredAssets({ data, error }) {
    console.log('Data'+JSON.stringify(data));
            this.data = data;

            if (data) {
                //mapData = [];
                var conts = data;
                for(var key in conts){
                    this.mapData.push({value:conts[key], key:key}); //Here we are creating the array to show on UI.
                }
                console.log('this.mapData'+JSON.stringify(this.mapData));
            }
```

}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have got the response in this @wire(getContacts)
    wiredAssets({ data, error }) {
        console.log('Data'+JSON.stringify(data));
                this.data = data;

                if (data) {
                    //mapData = [];
                    var conts = data;
                    for(var key in conts){
                        this.mapData.push({value:conts[key], key:key}); //Here we are creating the array to show on UI.
                    }
                    console.log('this.mapData'+JSON.stringify(this.mapData));
                }

Answer (score 2):

You need your data to look like this:

```
[ { key: key1, value: [ { index: 0, item: value1 }, ...] } ]
```

So, presuming you have a `Map<String, List<String>>`, you need to process both:

```
this.mapData = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => ({
  key,
  value: Object.entries(value).map(([index, item]) => ({ index, item })),
}));
```

Which gives you data that should look like:

```
[ { key: "child1 for parent1", value: [ { index: 0, item: "100" }, ... ] }, ... ]
```

Which means you need to slightly modify your template:

```
<tbody>
    <template for:each={mapData} for:item="mapkey" for:index="index">
        <tr key={mapkey.key}>
            <th scope="col">
             {mapkey.key}
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
            <template for:each={mapkey.value} for:item="mapval" for:index="index1">
              <div key={mapval.index}>
                {mapval.item}
              </div>
            </template>
          </th>
        </tr>
    </template>
```

Comment: I'm getting the response and changed as per the index based values but the HTML mapping doesn't happening its showing blank page the same code I have been used but still its showing blank page

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks